# How to justify the "least square" I used here?

Tags: least-squares, prediction

I have a stationary location estimation problem.

---

Constructed a model like this, used lmer to find the **$\beta$**.

$E(P_{i,j}) = \beta_0+\beta_1f_1[D^i(x,y)]+\beta_2f_2[A^i(x,y)]+R_i$
$(x,y)$: coordinates
$P_{i,j}$: is the collected variable
$R_i$: randam terms
$D(x,y), A(x,y)$: known function returns distance and angle. $D^i$ means the evaluation of $D(x,y)$ varies with respect to $i$
$f_1,f_2$: known functions

---

**Now, a new set of {$P_{i,j}$} is given, I want to find the $(x,y)$.**

A: $(x,y)=argmin[E(P_{i,j})-P_{i,j}]^2$
(It works some sense. But not so good result.)

**My question: does this make sense? what's the statistical reason behind this?**
I was thinking of 'projection', but feels not same.

B: $(x,y)=argmax[\sum_{i,j}{l_{i,j}}] \hspace{1cm} l_{i,j}$ is log-likelihood  of Observation $(P_{i,j})$

---

**Any comments on A, B, or other methods would be really appreciated!**

Comment: Why does $R_i$ appear in $E(P_{i,j})$, if it's random?

Comment: Should be (_{,} | R_i) instead.